# Github, couple of commits using wrong email, then some

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project that is in github for a client, using my professional email address.

I have been committing and doing some work properly, until recently I had changed the global config of git on my machine to my personal email and by mistake uploaded two commits into github using that identity. After which I changed the git id to my professional id and uploaded a third commit that has my professional credentials.

I do not want any commits on github that have my personal id but my professional one. how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the author of a commit in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

On your file .gitconfig you can configure the user you want to use.

For example I have :

```
[user]
    name = Franck 
    email = franck@gmail.com
```

You can add these by doing:

```
git config --global user.name "Franck"
git config --global user.email "franck@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Git came up with a script that will do what you are trying to do, it can be found here: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

That site has a 7 step process of changing the author of commits, otherwise you can try to just use the `git filter-branch` command on your own, but be careful!